# Search for files from another machine using Java

Tags: java, io

I need to create a small utility. Using Java, remotely (from another machine) I need to search for files (whether particular files exist or not). I would know exact names of files, or if not, I would know their partial names (so I will be using wildcards).

The problem is: I cannot install anything on that machine (it's a corporate box), but I am allowed FTP, Telnet, SSH login, etc. I would not want to use FTP because there are hundreds of directories and there's no way to know ahead of time where the files are each time (using ftp command `LS` on each directory every time is simply unproductive). So the best would be to use internal unix '`find`' command. Or a similar approach.

I need the best solution to the problem: how can I search for files (from hundreds of thousands files in many different folders) remotely on another machine.

Answer (score 3):

[Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) will allow you to connect quite easily to a remote machine and execute operations using SSH. There is not a lot of documentation, but these [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) shows about everything you can do, from basic Shell operations to SFTP and much more.

Answer (score 1):

You can locally exec ssh and have it execute the find command on another machine.

e.g.
    ssh user@host "find /home/foo -name index.*"

You can exec that from within the JVM and read the output from the process.